# How can I count the first initial in a specific column when a join makes the numbers go wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, distinct

I made a query for practice database and came up with something I would like to see from the database.

I wrote a query that gave me the first initial of the last name, the average salary, the total salary and the count of that initial.

```
SELECT      Left(Achternaam, 1) as '1e_Initiaal_Achternaam',
            cast(avg(Salaris) as Int) AS 'Gem. Salaris',
            round(cast(sum(Salaris) as Int),0) as 'Salaris',
            Count(Left(Achternaam, 1))
FROM        Werknemer
GROUP BY    Left(Achternaam, 1)
ORDER BY    Left(Achternaam, 1);
```

So far so good, everything as I wanted to see it.

[image]

But then I wanted to go a little further by adding the revenue/turnover to the overview, giving it a nice overview which is total useless in reality, but that does not matter in this case:

```
SELECT      Left(Achternaam, 1) as '1e_Initiaal_Achternaam',
            cast(avg(Salaris) as Int) AS 'Gem. Salaris',
            round(cast(sum(Salaris) as Int),0) as 'Salaris',
            Count(Left(Achternaam, 1)) as 'Eerste letter achternaam',
            sum(orderbedrag) as 'Order Waarde',
            sum(orderbedrag) / round(cast(sum(Salaris) as Int),0) as 'omzet per € salaris'
FROM        Werknemer
LEFT JOIN   Orders
On          werknemer.WerknemerID = orders.WerknemerID
GROUP BY    Left(Achternaam, 1)
ORDER BY    Left(Achternaam, 1);
```

[image]

So I got my view, but the first_initial (Eerste letter achternaam) is not correct anymore, because of the join. Now every 'Achternaam' is much more in the data now because I joined with the order data.

How can I still keep that first initial count and joining data? I thought I had to use a subquery, but I was not able to get it right. I tried to use the distinct function in a subquery, following the steps from the w3schools.com tutorial.

**Edit:**

thanks to the answer from T McKeown, I now have a different table.
But not what I wanted to achieve. I would like to understand what I have to change to get the table I want, assuming it is possible what I want.

this:

```
SELECT A.[1e_Initiaal_Achternaam],
       A.[Gem. Salaris], 
       A.[Salaris],
       A.[Count],
       (SELECT sum(orderbedrag) 
          FROM Orders WHERE WerknemerID = A.WerknemerID ) as [Order Waarde],
       (SELECT sum(orderbedrag) / round(cast(A.Salaris as Int),0)
          FROM Orders WHERE WerknemerID = A.WerknemerID ) as [AVG Salaris]
  FROM (

SELECT WerknemerID,
       Left(Achternaam, 1) as '1e_Initiaal_Achternaam',
       cast(avg(Salaris) as Int) AS 'Gem. Salaris',
       round(cast(sum(Salaris) as Int),0) as 'Salaris',
       Count(Left(Achternaam, 1)) as 'Count'
FROM   [dbo].[Werknemer]
GROUP BY Left(Achternaam, 1), WerknemerID
) AS A
ORDER BY A.[1e_Initiaal_Achternaam];
```

results in this:
[image]

As you can see, there are multiple rows with the B, multiple rows with the P, etc.

Comment: Usually one use a cross (or outer) apply to join the sub tables and aggregate inside the apply, this avoids the duplication of rows.

Comment: please review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways, but here is a way, create your first output as is, use a derived table, add all the keys and columns you need from the Werknemer table and then add some sub selects for the aggregates in the outer SQL.

```
SELECT A.[1e_Initiaal_Achternaam],
       A.[Gem. Salaris], 
       A.[Salaris],
       A.[Count],
       (SELECT sum(orderbedrag) 
          FROM Orders WHERE WerknemerID = A.WerknemerID ) as [Order Waarde],
       (SELECT sum(orderbedrag) / round(cast(A.Salaris as Int),0)
          FROM Orders WHERE WerknemerID = A.WerknemerID ) as [Salaris2]
  FROM (

SELECT WerknemerID,
       Left(Achternaam, 1) as '1e_Initiaal_Achternaam',
       cast(avg(Salaris) as Int) AS 'Gem. Salaris',
       round(cast(sum(Salaris) as Int),0) as 'Salaris',
       Count(Left(Achternaam, 1)) as 'Count'
FROM   Werknemer
GROUP BY WerknemerID, Left(Achternaam, 1)
) AS A
ORDER BY A.1e_Initiaal_Achternaam
```

Created a derived table named A, join to it and do the aggregates. I had to add an extra column to the list of workers.

Notice the Order By is in the outer SQL, and no idea if it performs well for you.

Comment: thanks. I tried it, it gave an error for syntax error near '.1e'. I fixed it by putting the last line in brackets: ORDER BY A.[1e_Initiaal_Achternaam]; but then it returned this strange error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Werknemer'.

even when I drag this table into the query, it returns this error: 
FROM   [dbo].[Werknemer]

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.Werknemer'.

I don't get it. Had this issue before with some other query while I tried to join tables. the names are perfecly right but stil this issue 'invalid object name'.

Comment: you need to figure that out... i assume you are running this query in the right DB? i can't see your DB... check the SQL..  The point of my answer is to show you how to do the grouping in the inner/derived table part and then add subselect aggregates.

Comment: I changed something, I now get a nice table. However, I suppose because of the group by on WerknemerID, I have multiple rows with a B, multiple rows with a P for example. I will add this to my question.